# What's the widest wide-angle lens available to Canon Full Frame DSLRs?

Tags: dslr, wide-angle, full-frame

Is there anything wider than the Sigma 12-24mm? Are there any attachments I can put on my camera to get an even wider focal length?

Comment: Do you want rectilinear, or is fisheye OK? Canon sells an [8-15mm fisheye](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/lenses/ef/ultra-wide-zoom/ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm).

Comment: You might also consider using a fisheye lens and using software to transform the image to rectilinear perspective.

Answer (score 4):

The widest rectilinear lens available for any full-frame is the [Canon EF 11-24mm F/4L USM](http://www.canon.ca/inetCA/en/products/method/gp/pid/43938). To get a wider field-of-view, you need a fisheye or stitch multiple images. Like many extremely wide lenses, a 11-24mm lens does not allow attachments at the front, only filters at the back but those will not help you get a wider angle-of-view.

Comment: I know OP asked for a rectilinear lens, but for completeness it's good to include that Canon makes the widest fisheye zoom in it's EF 8-15mm f/4L, and there are some 8mm and even 6.5mm prime lenses available from third parties.

Comment: @Caleb by 6.5mm, do you mean the Opteka 6.5mm? That's the same lens Samyang/Rokinon calls an 8mm fisheye, and it's crop, not full frame (ditto Sigma's 4.5mm circular fisheye and rectilinear 8-16mm).

Comment: @inkista I didn't realize the Opteka 6.5mm and Rokinon 8mm lenses were the same; it's weird then that the Rokinon is about 50% more expensive. In some cases that lens is described as being for APS-C sensors, but it should work as a "circular fisheye" meaning that it produces a round image on a full frame sensor. This is also true of Sigma's 8mm prime and Canon's 8-15mm zoom at the wide(er) end.

Comment: @Caleb, um, no. The Samyang 8 is designed as a diagonal for APS-C, and the petals screw with the shape; it [won't be circular on full frame](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/52965614) unless you shave off the petals. The Sigma 8mm otoh, is designed as a full-frame circular (I know, I shoot one on my 5DMkII). The 8-15 is unique--diagonal on crop doesn't _always_ equal circular on full frame.

Comment: @inkista The Rokinon version, at least, has a [removable hood](http://www.amazon.com/Rokinon-HD8M-C-Fisheye-Removeable-Fixed-Non-Zoom/dp/B008X1C4IY).

Comment: @Caleb. Ah, yes. Forgot they added that for version II because so many people were shaving it for full frame. :)  But--nitpick--it's still [a bit off from being circular](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/50556597), as you don't get the whole circle in the frame; just as [the Sigma 8 circular is a bit off from being diagonal on crop](https://www.flickr.com/photos/inkista/3044408256/) (black corners). And most straight-up fisheye shooters prefer full-frame coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Rectilinear and wider that 12mm on full frame is hard to get, but also hard to use.  It's not usual to need more than this exceptionally wide angle in this context.  The biggest issue with wider lenses is that they are more likely to suffer from flare ( just trying to avoid the Sun or a bright light source in shot can be impossible ) and are ( as a general rule ) more prone to distortions.

If you need a wider image then consider stitching panoramas in software.  There's [very good free software, like Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/), that will do this and you normally just need overlapping images to do it.  Stitching means you can employ images shot with a lens less prone to distortion and combine them to make a final image that is more detailed and less affected by optical distortion.